# Default entities in reference list

Tags: views, 8, entities

I'm implementing a way for providing documents to different users for download on Drupal 8.

Each document has a category (implemented as own nodes).

Some categories are global.
Some categories are specific for different users.
This is controlled by an additional field you can select a user from.

When creating a new document, only "legal" categories are supposed to be selectable.
Legal are: Corresponding and global categories.

Using Business Rules I'm able to update the list of categories depending of the selected user using a view with a contextual filter.

But I have trouble to add the global categories to the list, independent of the selected user.

Ideally I would make use of two filters combined with and OR condition. But since one of my filters is contextual, I'm not sure if that works.

My next idea would be to "union" two views. One containing only global categories and one containing the specific categories contextual.
But I'm also not sure if that works.

Could someone nudge me into the right direction what's the way to go here?

Comment: Your current implementation description isn't very clear. Are you talking about nodes when mentioning categories? Are they "labeled" global or user-specific through a user reference? "Views Contextual Filters OR" module probably won't help unless your "global" can be contextual. You can always create two views displays (maybe one as Attachment to the other) and show them one below the other. If you need to sort them in-between then [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) can help to insert one view display _into_ another, although it's performance intensive.

Comment: @prkos Thanks for your time. - I edited the question and added a few details. - Categories are distinguished by a field they have. Either it holds a user or it's empty. In the latter case the category is assumed to be "global". - Showing two views below the other probably won't work, because I need them as an entity reference in the backend, so I can pick a category for the document. - I take a look at the mentioned module as soon I'm back at work.

Comment: It would make more sense to have Categories as Taxonomy terms, and not nodes. Any reason why? So IIUC you have nodes files, that reference Category nodes, that reference users (or not). You didn't add the requirement about entity reference views to the question, that's new info and very relevant. Is your views listing documents or categories? Is the current user always Corresponding?

Comment: I thought the reference list was implied in the question, but I'll add an explicit mention, thank you. - The categories are supposed to have an icon for front-end display. That's why are nodes rather than terms. - The view(s) in question list categories.

Comment: Taxonomy terms can also have icons (as fields) just like nodes ;)

Comment: Huh. Good to know. But that won't solve my problem, right?

Comment: Nope, referencing taxonomy terms also goes through an entity reference field, just like referencing nodes, it just makes a lot more sense structurally on any site. Post your views screenshots when you try it out if you get stuck. Views config, Contextuals config, for both displays if you use Views Field view.